# How do i use my WordPress login to sign in with FTP and upload files into the free space?

Tags: html, wordpress, plugins

Sorry but i am being a bit of a noob with these questions. How do i login with my wordpress logins and upload a plugin into the folders? Such a basic task but wordpress doesnt provide the most basic idea of doing just that.
Thank you Guys

Comment: lmgtfy http://codex.wordpress.org/FTP_Clients

Comment: if you don't have an FTP account, you probably won't be able to add plugins,  contact your host.

Comment: This might have been better to ask on [wordpress.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your web host is GoDaddy or something that uses cPanel, you should be able to use their build in FTP file manager. If not, you will need to download a file manager (FileZilla was already mentioned) to your local machine and login with your admin credentials.

Once you're logged in via FTP, you can upload the plugin at the `/wp-content/plugins` directory.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using a custom WordPress install, not the WordPress.com site. Your login credentials will be for the server, ie they're different than those that you use to log in to WordPress. Get those credentials and use an FTP client ([e.g. FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/)) to upload the files. There are always WordPress FTP plugins you could use as well. Hope that helps.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you sir! I am suprised why my question was down voted :S:S:S:S